# Why does this package (ppa:ondrej/php5, it's PHP 5.5) break the apache2 installation?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, ubuntu-12.04

### Problem

Currently this package (ppa:ondrej/php5) is quite popular for installing the latest version of PHP 5.5. I've worked quite much with it, and everything ran smoothy, on several (dev) servers. But from today (?) this breaks the apache2 installation (it empties the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file). This is reproduceable.

### Way to reproduce (on naked Ubuntu 64 12.04 LTS)

```
// basic installs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php5
```

Apache is fine, `nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default` has valid content now

```
// getting PHP 5.5.x
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties (for add-apt-repository)
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5
// php -v shows successful install of PHP 5.5.x now
```

Apache is broken, `nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default` is empty now

### Question

Why does this happen ? According to [https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/php5) there were no changes in the last few days.

Comment: Note: I suppose this is not a PHP package issue, it also happen when upgrading to Apache 2.4 in general. In this case the php package also upgrades apache 2.4 automatically

Comment: The author of ondrej/php5 sent me this: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=716880

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade` after adding the ppa should do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This PPA now comes with an upgrade to Apache 2.4

And the config files of Apache 2.4 have significant differences, including sites-available/sites-enable filename and syntax differences.

The problem you are experiencing is exactly because the config filename change.